# Will .gitignore file work for local pull?

Tags: git

I have a situation where I have cloned a github repo locally say here **/home/user/IU**. Now I'm running apache and the root for apache is **/var/www/** and my website root is **/var/www/IU** which is  clone of **/home/user/IU**. Every time I want to see my website in browser, I would do **git pull** at **/var/www/IU**. This is fine but I don't want to pulling all files from **/home/user/IU** to **/var/www/IU** but I want to keep pull and pushing all files from rmeote to **/home/user/IU**. Can .gitignore help me? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible using `git pull` and/or .gitignore - you cannot clone or pull only some folders. This is typical for Git, as  most things are done per repository (cloning, pulling, committing, branching, ...).

That said, you are probably using the wrong tool for the job. It seems you want to use Git to deploy a website. Git in general and `git pull` in particular is **not a deployment tool** - even though some people use it as such. You will constantly run into problems if you try this.

Instead, use some dedicated tool for the deployment. Many technologies have their own deployment methods (e.g. with Java web apps you use WARs, with Ruby on Rails it's mod_rails, etc.). You can also just write some script to copy the files.